# Joining two strings within a list of list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists containing:

```
animal = [[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3, 'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]
```

and I want to join the string elements in each list inside the animal table so that it becomes a single string:

```
 animal = [[1, 'Crocodile, Lion'],[2, 'Eagle, Sparrow'],[3,'Hippo, Platypus, Deer']]
```

I tried using a for loop to join them:

```
for i in range(len(animal)):
     ''.join(animal[1:]) #string at index 1 and so on
print(animal)
```

I'm getting a type error saying "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found".

Comment: you can use this `', '.join([x for x in animal if type(x) == str])` then create a list without the strings `new_list = [x for x in animal if type(x) != str]` then append the string to the new list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change needed, you just forgot the index i in your loop:

```
animal = [[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3, 'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]

merged_animal = []

for element in animal:
    merged_animal.append([element[0], ", ".join(element[1:])])

print(merged_animal)
```

But if you know list-comprehensions, better use them as shown in many answers.

Answer (score 1):

`animal` could be called `table`, and should indicate that it's not just a single animal. It also shouldn't be called `animals`, because it's not just a list of animals.

Thanks to [unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), you can split your sub-lists directly into an integer and a list of animals:

```
>>> table = [[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3, 'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]
>>> [[i, ', '.join(animals)] for (i, *animals) in table]
[[1, 'Crocodile, Lion'], [2, 'Eagle, Sparrow'], [3, 'Hippo, Platypus, Deer']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [[a[0], ','.join(a[1:])] for a in animal]
>>> [[1, 'Crocodile,Lion'], [2, 'Eagle,Sparrow'], [3, 'Hippo,Platypus,Deer']]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

`animal[1:]` is the following list

```
>>> animal[1:]
[[2, 'Eagle', 'Sparrow'], [3, 'Hippo', 'Platypus', 'Deer']]
```

what do you expect to happen if you `join` it in every iteration of your loop?
The second problem is that you do not assign the return value of `join` to anything, so even if the operation would not throw an error, you would lose the result.

Here's a solution with [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> animal = [[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3,'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]
>>> [[head, ', '.join(tail)] for head, *tail in animal]
[[1, 'Crocodile, Lion'], [2, 'Eagle, Sparrow'], [3, 'Hippo, Platypus, Deer']]
```

Here's one without:

```
>>> [[sub[0], ', '.join(sub[1:])] for sub in animal]
[[1, 'Crocodile, Lion'], [2, 'Eagle, Sparrow'], [3, 'Hippo, Platypus, Deer']]
```

Comment: @EricDuminil sometimes a well written, comprehensive answer takes a few seconds longer than the fastest colt on SO.

Answer (score 0):

`animal` is a list of lists so you need an extra index. You see this by adding

```
print(animal[i])
print(animal[i][0])
print(animal[i][1])
```

etc in the loop

```
animal = [[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3, 'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]

for i in range(len(animal)):
    print(animal[i][1:])
    animal[i][1] = ' '.join(animal[i][1:]) #string at index 1 and so on
    del animal[i][2:]


print(animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the type error is coming because you are applying `join()` on the list animal not on the sublists of list animal.

You should also keep in mind that join does not edit the original list, it just returns the new string.

Hence if you keep the above two things in mind your new code will look something like this

```
for i in range(len(animal)):
 animal[i] = [animal[i][0], ', '.join(animal[i][1:])] #string at index 1 and so on
print(animal)
```

the above code replaces each sublist with another sublist containing the sublist number and a string formed by joining the remaining part of original sublist with a `', '` *(note your mistake here, you were joining with an empty character but your requirement is a comma and a space).*

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=[[1, 'Crocodile','Lion'],[2, 'Eagle','Sparrow'],[3, 'Hippo','Platypus','Deer']]

l2 = list(map(lambda x: [x[0],"{}, {}".format(x[1],x[2])],l1))
print(l2)
```

Comment: When you provide an answer it should be more descriptive.

Comment: thanks for your info. I have to learn stackoverflow. it was my first answer.

Comment: yeap that is fine. Explain why you do this in an appropriate manner.